# Does EF core always require a primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I defined a class (as the model for EF), but when I ran migrations to update the DB schema I got this error:

```
The entity type 'xyz' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

Sure, it's easy enought fix to add:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

From a domain model point of view I do not need a primary key on this entity.  It is a dependent entity with one-many relationship and doesn't need to be unique.

So, this is more of a curiousity (than a serious problem) but is there a way not to define a primary key?

Comment: Yes you need a PK. Also, to not have a PK on a table is very unusual.

Comment: W/o PK EF won't be able to update/delete the entity. Hence they decided to require it. It doesn't need to be part of the class - could be a [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), but then again it would be hard if not impossible to update/delete it. Not sure if EF Core 2.2 [Collection of owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) could handle it.

Comment: EF needs to compose a unique ID for a record in order to update it. Even though you have a collection on a related entity, when EF goes to update a specific row, it needs to know how to tell the DB which row to update. This does not mean that a table must have a PK defined, but rather EF just needs to be told how to uniquely identify an individual row. (I.e. a concatenated key made up of FKs for example) Just be sure that the combination is absolutely unique or you can get errors or incorrect updates from EF.